# Check if Start and End Time Overlaps

Tags: typescript, angular8

I'm trying to check if a start and end time overlap

```
   export class StartTimeEndTimeWrapper {
        StartTime: Time;
        EndTime: Time;
    }
   timeSlots: StartTimeEndTimeWrapper;



if ((this.timeSlots.EndTime.hours - this.timeSlots.StartTime.hours) <= 0)
            {
            alert("first overlap");
            }
```

But the hour part is undefined.

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you forget to initialize timeSlots object?

Comment: @Charlie Cai I did not initialise .I tried initialising with a time string.But there was some time mismatch when creating `Time` object from string.

Comment: is there a Time class in js,I only use Date class and momentjs for timestamp operation?

Comment: @CharlieCai Its in angular 8

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize `StartTime` and `EndTime` with a Time object inside `timeSlots` before you can use those properties, something like this:

```js
timeSlots: StartTimeEndTimeWrapper;

constructor() {
  this.timeSlots = new StartTimeEndTimeWrapper();
  this.timeSlots.StartTime = { hours: 9, minutes: 0 };
  this.timeSlots.EndTime = { hours: 8, minutes: 0 };

  // That actually works fine
  if (this.timeSlots.EndTime.hours - this.timeSlots.StartTime.hours <= 0) {
    console.log("first overlap");
  }
}
```

Comment: Still not working .. seems like a binding issue with Time.